# How to get only JSON in response

Tags: php

When I debug a site via Chrome browser I get JSON response. But when I try to do this via PHP I get an error message

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
```

Thanks for any help.

For exaplme:
Things to do in Chrome:
Go to page: http://gruper.pl/warszawa and on the bottom you will see a button "Wiecej ofert". After click you will see in a debug:

```
http://gruper.pl/DataProvider.php?cityId=51&categoryId=0&mainNaviId=1&showBTile=true&page=1
```

and response:

```
[{"ID_PAGE":"59199","ID_CITY":"3952","main_city":"3952","date_start":"2014-02-23 18:00:00","date_end":"2014-03-01 23:59:00","price".....
```

Is there any possibility to get the same in PHP?

My code is:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://gruper.pl/DataProvider.php?cityId=51&categoryId=0&mainNaviId=1&showBTile=true&page=1';

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  =>  "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" ,
                      "Accept:application/json\r\n" .
                      "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n" .
                      "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest\r\n",
        'method'  => 'GET'
    ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = (file_get_contents($url, false, $context));

?>


<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head> 

</html>
```

Comment: What you refer to as JSON response is merely the way Chrome (and every other browser) displays response headers, JSON would look similar to this example: http://json.org/example

Comment: Rephrase your question - it's not clear what is your problem.

Comment: Can you check again? I placed new version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get JSON in response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987424/how-to-get-json-in-response)

Comment: Please don't **ask the same question twice**

Answer (score 0):

I think that Chrome is automatically converting code to json. Be more explicit by using **json_encode()** in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using json_encode

```
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Can you check again? I have change description. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you first check your PHP configuration, make sure that `allow_url_fopen` [1] is set to "On", if you have to change the setting, don't forget to restart Apache (or whichever webserver you use). Next, use the URL from your initial post and check if you get the expected result using inline debugging:

```
$url= 'http://gruper.pl/DataProvider.php?cityId=51&categoryId=0&mainNaviId=1&showBTile=true&page=1';
$contents= file_get_contents($url);
print 'Content returned: '.$contents.'---'."\n";
```

Next we'll check if the returned content contains proper JSON values, add the following code:

```
try {
  $arrConverted= json_decode($contents);
  print 'JSON-decoded representation:';
  print_r($arrConverted);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  print 'JSON-decoding failed, the error was: '.$ex->getMessage();
}
```

You normally don't need to create a context stream to grab web pages, there is a built-in support for default protocols like FTP and HTTP in most functions [2].

Let us know how you got so far.

[1] http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen
[2] https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php