# How to get JSON in response

Tags: php

When I debug a site via Chrome browser I get JSON response. But when I try to do this via PHP I get an error message.

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found

Thanks for any help.

For example:

Things to do in Chrome:

Go to page: http://gruper.pl/warszawa and on the bottom you will see a button "Wiecej ofert". After click you will see in a debug:

```
http://gruper.pl/DataProvider.php?cityId=51&categoryId=0&mainNaviId=1&showBTile=true&page=1
```

and response:

```
[{"ID_PAGE":"59199","ID_CITY":"3952","main_city":"3952","date_start":"2014-02-23 18:00:00","date_end":"2014-03-01 23:59:00","price".....
```

Is there any possibility to get the same in PHP?

My code is:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://gruper.pl/DataProvider.php?cityId=51&categoryId=0&mainNaviId=1&showBTile=true&page=1';

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  =>  "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
                      "Accept:application/json\r\n" .
                      "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n" .
                      "X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest\r\n",
        'method'  => 'GET'
    ),
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = (file_get_contents($url, false, $context));

?>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head> 

</html>
```

Comment: There's a comma `,` after the first header. Replace it with a period `.`, and see if it helps. My guess is, it will, because the most important headers are most likely the last ones. It's a sneaky bug; hard to detect, because it's no syntax error.

Comment: I have changed it, but it is not a problem.
Problem is that url:
http://gruper.pl/DataProvider.php?cityId=51&categoryId=0&mainNaviId=1&showBTile=true&page=1
doesn't work even in browser.

Comment: blank page? do you have error reporting on just in case?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it. So that is the reason that I put "solution" with Chrome browser what to do to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that URL will return a 404 HTTP status code unless these headers are set:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://gruper.pl/warszawa
```

So this will work:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://gruper.pl/DataProvider.php?cityId=51&categoryId=0&mainNaviId=1&showBTile=true&page=1';

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n" .
                    "Referer: http://gruper.pl/warszawa"
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = (file_get_contents($url, false, $context));

echo $result;

?>
```